# Not able to run the jar file during startup of system

Tags: linux, jar

I have RedHat linux. Intention is to start the java based GUI app after linux system finishes boot up. I have edited /etc/rc.local and kept

/usr/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java -jar /home/rfgwtest/Desktop/CEM/CEM_v2.0_Beta08/CEM_v2.0_Beta08/PME_CEM.jar &

at the end of the file. I am able to run this file for testing by executing the file on prompt. no errors of path or so.

what is missing as part of this? i have found this tip from the RedHat website

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html

is there a common way to do this across the different kind of distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, creating a desktop entry will do it.
To do that,

```
$ cd
$ nano .config/autostart/javaApp.desktop
```

now, write this inside it,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=usr/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java -jar /home/rfgwtest/Desktop/CEM/CEM_v2.0_Beta08/CEM_v2.0_Beta08/PME_CEM.jar
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Name[en_IN]=StartJAR
Name=StartJAR
Comment[en_IN]=Jar comment
Comment=Jar comment
```

save the file and then, restart or re-login to the system.

Comment: not able to create file under .config/. I don't find /autostart folder . any pointers to proceed

Comment: the folder is not "/autostart" but ".config/autostart" ie, its inside the .config directory and not in the root directory. 
Also, if it do not exist there in the .config directory, just create it. 
The command "$ mkdir .config/autostart", will create the directory (if executed form user-name directory)